# Is it possible to know if a System.Object was actually specified as dynamic (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I have a couple of scenarios that cover this, but I'll write specifically about the one that's easier to demonstrate

I have a factory interface:

```
interface IFactory
{
  Create<T>();
}
```

And a piece of code that uses it thus:

```
public static void func(IFactory f)
{
  var o = f.Create<dynamic>();
}
```

Now, in an implementation of `Create<T>()` - is is there any way, via reflection over `T`, to determine if the caller is intending dynamic dispatch on their object as opposed to a straightforward `object`?  I have a class where being able to make that distinction would be quite useful...

I've had a look to see if I can find attributes on the type or something like that, but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic` is in the eye of the caller *only*, so no; that isn't possible AFAIK. As far as `Create` is concerned it is just `object`.

Comment: Yes, and of course different languages ultimately bind differently, but I was hoping, given you can 'take a step back' whilst binding a dynamic expression in IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, that at least c# might offer a way to do the same at the very start of a dynamic expression.   Damn!